# xpath expression not working properly on HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to search for a html node using xpath expressions.
The objective is to match all `tr` nodes which have 2 children `td` nodes with the attribute `class="shiftHolder"` (the seconds `tr` in the example).

```
<table>
       <tr class="staffRow">
          <td class="staff" data-staffid="2" data-primaryrole="1">
             <div class="sn">Leyla-claire Collins</div>
          </td>
          <td class="shiftHolder">
          </td>
          <td class="shiftHolder unavailable">
             Holiday
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="staffRow">
          <td class="staff" data-staffid="11" data-primaryrole="4">
             <div class="sn">Natale Dersley</div>
          </td>
          <td class="shiftHolder">
          </td>
          <td class="shiftHolder">
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

The following expressions are working [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html), [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath), and [here](http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester) but not on [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com), both `tr` are returned.

```
//tr[@class='staffRow'][count(td[@class='shiftHolder'])=2][td[@class='staff' and @data-staffid and @data-primaryrole][div[@class='sn']]]

//tr[@class='staffRow' and count(td[@class='shiftHolder'])=2 and td[@class='staff' and @data-staffid and @data-primaryrole and div[@class='sn']]]
```

Is there any difference on HtmlAgilityPack that I'm not aware of?